# VueJS - standard practice for ordering functions in export?

Tags: vue.js

New to Vue and wondering if there is there a standard practice for ordering the exports? The `name` seems to always be at the top and the lifecycle hooks seem to be in the order of the lifescycle but I'm not sure about the rest (`data`, `computed`, etc.).

Thoughts?

e.g.

```
export default {
  name: "component-name",
  props: {},
  components: {},
  computed: {},
  data() {},
  watch: {},
  beforeCreate() {},
  created() {},
  beforeMount() {},
  mounted() {},
  beforeUpdate() {},
  updated() {},
  beforeDestroy() {},
  destroyed() {},
  methods: {},
};
```

Comment: hope it helps https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the rules of the eslint-plugin-vue v6.2.2 (for Vue 2.x), You can read about it here: https://github.com/vuejs/eslint-plugin-vue/blob/v6.2.2/docs/rules/README.md, this is the order:

```
{
  "vue/order-in-components": ["error", {
    "order": [
      "el",
      "name",
      "parent",
      "functional",
      ["delimiters", "comments"],
      ["components", "directives", "filters"],
      "extends",
      "mixins",
      "inheritAttrs",
      "model",
      ["props", "propsData"],
      "fetch",
      "asyncData",
      "data",
      "computed",
      "watch",
      "LIFECYCLE_HOOKS",
      "methods",
      "head",
      ["template", "render"],
      "renderError"
    ]
  }]
}
```

Here you can read the Vue style guide and the rules priority information https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/

Comment: No problem, nice to know that it was useful.